# How to preserve query string or session variable when redirecting in routes.php in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've got some addon domains pointing to my server at the directory /public_html/. Let's say the addon domains are red-bananas.com and blue-bananas.com, and when someone loads that domain I want it to point to a specific action in my controller. So I have this code at the bottom of my routes.php file:

```
Route::get('red', 'BananasController@red');
Route::get('blue', 'BananasController@blue'); 
Route::any('/', function()
{

    switch( Request::getHost() ){
        case 'red-bananas.com':
            return redirect()->action('BananasController@red');
            break;
        case 'blue-bananas.com':
            return redirect()->action('BananasController@blue');
            break;

    }
});
```

I notice if you were to go to red-bananas.com, you get redirected to the URL red-bananas.com/red, and if you go to blue-bananas.com you get redirected to blue-bananas.com/blue. This is fine, but I sometimes have tracking query strings I need on my URLs, like this:

red-bananas.com?tid=123

Ideally I'd like to be able to store in the session the value of '123' to 'tid', but if I do Session::put('tid', '123') above

```
return redirect()->action('BananasController@red');
```

It doesn't work - nothing gets stored in the session and the tracking data is lost. How can I preserve the tracking data? I need someone to be able to load up the URL red-bananas.com?tid=123 and it triggers the red function in my BananasController where I can access the value of tid.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be:

```
switch( Request::getHost() ){
    case 'red-bananas.com':
        Route::get('/{tid?}', ['as' => 'bananas.red', 'uses' => 'BananasController@red']);
        break;
    // ... repeat for other cases
}
```

And then in your BananasController:

```
public function red($tid = null)
{
    // ... whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually [pass a second parameter (an array) to the route action](https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#redirecting-controller-actions) which will become the parameters, so you can do something like:

```
Route::get('red', 'BananasController@red');
Route::get('blue', 'BananasController@blue'); 
Route::any('/', function()
{

    switch( Request::getHost() ){
        case 'red-bananas.com':
            return redirect()->action('BananasController@red', request()->all());
            break;
        case 'blue-bananas.com':
            return redirect()->action('BananasController@blue', request()->all());
            break;

    }
});
```

Comment: What should the controller be then? I implemented this code, and then in the red function of BananasController I have this:

`public function red($data = null){

        return print_r($data, true);
      

    }`

But nothing shows up.